# how to add PayPal payment in opencart 2.1.0.1 with custom design

Tags: paypal, opencart2.x

I was tryed to install PayPal Payments Standard in opencart 2.1.0.1 with custom design of payments page but it doesn't show on page with payment method. If some one can help me with advise how to make it work.If is need I can post  code of page with  payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem Paypal doesn't support all currency i use in opencart ,that's why i will try Braintree,  support more currency.